# How to configure a MS Surface Pro to restart after AC power loss and restoration?

Tags: windows-10, uefi, microsoft-surface-pro

I have a MS Surface Pro that is being used as a kiosk. After an AC power failure and then restoration of power, I want the PC to turn itself back on. I have looked at the BIOS/UEFI of the device and there are only 4 settings unrelated to power issues. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If the BIOS doesn't support it, then IME you're pretty much SOL.

Comment: I too am trying to figure this out. I wonder if there is a possibility of writing a custom BIOS...